# How do I pipe data received via bluetooth into an mp3 file between android devices?

Tags: android, bluetooth, mp3, send, file-transfer

QUESTION: How do I pipe data received (sent via bluetooth chat sample code) into an mp3 file?

AIM: To transfer an mp3 file from one android phone to another using a simple bluetooth file transfer method.

METHOD: Using the bluetooth chat sample provided by the Android SDK I piped the MP3 file into a byte array and then transmitted the data to the second device.

CURRENT STATUS: The data is received by the second device, (I checked by outputting the stream to the screen) however I am unable to open an file and pipe the data into it, give it an ".mp3" extension and then play it.

**BluetoothChat.java**

```
public byte[] lilfilebuffer = null;


private void sendMessage(String message) {


    lilfilebuffer = read(new File("/sdcard/media/07_The-organ.mp3"));
    mChatService.write(lilfilebuffer);


}


private byte[] read(final File file) {
    Throwable pending = null;
    FileInputStream in = null;
    final byte buffer[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(file);
        in.read(buffer);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        pending = new RuntimeException("Exception occured on reading file "
                        + file.getAbsolutePath(), e);
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
                try {
                        in.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        if (pending == null) {
                                pending = new RuntimeException(
                                        "Exception occured on closing file" 
                             + file.getAbsolutePath(), e);
                        }
                }
        }
        if (pending != null) {
                throw new RuntimeException(pending);
        }
    }
    return buffer;
}




// The Handler that gets information back from the BluetoothChatService
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
            if(D) Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);
            switch (msg.arg1) {
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                setStatus(getString(R.string.title_connected_to, mConnectedDeviceName));
                mConversationArrayAdapter.clear();
                break;
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                setStatus(R.string.title_connecting);
                break;
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_LISTEN:
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE:
                setStatus(R.string.title_not_connected);
                break;
            }
            break;
        case MESSAGE_WRITE:
            byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;

            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/media/testsong.mp3");
                out.write(writeBuf);
                out.close();

                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                { 
                //System.out.println("Exception ");

                }
            break;
        case MESSAGE_READ:
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;

            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/media/testsong.mp3");

                out.write(readBuf);
                out.close();



                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                { 
                //System.out.println("Exception ");

                }



            break;
        case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
            // save the connected device's name
            mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to "
                           + mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case MESSAGE_TOAST:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.getData().getString(TOAST),
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

**BluetoothChatService.java**

```
public void write(byte[] out) {

    ConnectedThread r;

    synchronized (this) {
        if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
        r = mConnectedThread;
    }

    r.write(out);
}

private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread: " + socketType);
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;


        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;


        while (true) {
            try {

                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);


                mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                BluetoothChatService.this.start();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(buffer);


            mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                    .sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }


}}
```

Comment: Can you please edit the title with a relevent question..

Comment: Also create a miniature example to explain your problem.. Don't paste your entire code in to the question..Only post relevent parts of the code..

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @Krishnabhadra, I've updated as per your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything special about the data or MP3 file.  You just need to write it to disk before playing it.

I have an app ([BlueMuze](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alostpacket.bluemuze)) that does this exactly, and the part I found more difficult was establishing and maintaining the Bluetooth connection as well as getting the pairing timing correct.

The problem with your code however is that **you appear to be creating and writing to a new file for every 1024 bytes.**

You create a new `FileOutputStream` each time the 'chat' handler reads the message sent by the service.  Rather, you just need to create the `FileOutputStream` once and write the buffer to it until you reach the end of the file, then close the `FileOutputStream`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am having a problem with send simple image file over bluetooth using bluetooth chat sample. Actually, My requirement was an send any file oevr bluetooth. For this how can I set the buffer size, how to receive small chunk of data and combine it at the receiver side. Could u please share me your code.